# responseText doesn't return the success message

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to insert data into database using Ajax and PHP. Now what's the problem is that the responseText doesn't return any message but the insertion done sucessfully
Here is my script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function aa() 
    {
        var x=new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.open("GET","ajax.php?na="+document.getElementById("t1").value+" &ag="+document.getElementById("t2").value+"&des="+document.getElementById("t3").value+"&em="+document.getElementById("t4").value+" ",true);
        x.send(null);
        document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML=x.responseText;
    }
</script>
```

This is my ajax.php

```
<?php 

$mysql_host = 'localhost'; 
$mysql_database = 'proj1'; 
$mysql_user = 'root'; 
$mysql_password='';
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli))
{
    echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$name = $_GET['na'];
$ag = $_GET['ag'];
$des = $_GET['des'];
$em = $_GET['em'];
$sql=mysqli_query($mysqli,"insert into ajax_sample (id,name,age,desig,email) values ( '', '$name', '$ag' ,'$des', '$em'  )");
if($sql)
{
    echo "Successfully Inserted....";
}
?>
```

and this is my html page

```
     <form name="f1" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="t1" placeholder="enter name"><br><br>
    <input type="text" id="t2" placeholder="enter age"><br><br>
    <input type="text" id="t3" placeholder="enter designation"><br><br>
    <input type="text" id="t4" placeholder="enter email"><br><br>
    <input type="button" id="b1" value="submit" onclick="aa();">
    <div id="d1"></p></div>
</form>
```

Comment: If you are not familiar with Ajax, I **highly** recommend to read a **tutorial** first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: If you call the php-script directly by inserting "ajax.php?na=smth&ag=smthElse ..." into the browser address bar. Is the success-message displayed?

Comment: @felix Sure I'll go through it.. Thanks

Comment: @michael.zech no it will not...

Comment: It should. Looks allright. I would add an else-branch with another message. Then it has to display something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to hook into async change callback with `onreadystatechange` to handle the case when the XHR request is done. Then `.responseText` will be set on it.

```
function aa() 
{
    var x=new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open("GET","ajax.php?na="+document.getElementById("t1").value+" &ag="+document.getElementById("t2").value+"&des="+document.getElementById("t3").value+"&em="+document.getElementById("t4").value+" ",true);
    x.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (x.readyState == 4 && x.statusCode == 200) {
        document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML=x.responseText;
      }
    };
    x.send(null);
}
```

It is important to understand that an `XMLHttpRequest` is asynchronous. That basically means you request a URL to be access via JavaScript and the browser/JS engine goes off and does that. You can hook into when the request is finished by using `onreadystatechange`. The MDN page linked below has a table with the potential values for `readyState`.

MDN: [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and tutorial [Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: The check should be ``if (x.readyState == 4 && x.statusCode == 200)``, but you can also use the ``x.addEventListener('load', function () {...`` if you're assuming HTML5 compliance, which makes it easier since you don't have to include that if statement.